# how do re add my id"..." to drag/drop images after moved?

Tags: jquery, class, addclass

Jquery Code

```
function itemInSpot(drag_item,spot)
{
var oldSpotItem = $(spot).find('img');
if(oldSpotItem.length>100) {
    oldSpotItem.appendTo('#itembox4').draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
}
var item = $('<img />');
item.attr('src',drag_item.attr('src')).attr('class',drag_item.attr('class')).appendTo(spot).draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
drag_item.remove(); // remove the old object
}

 $(document).ready(function() {
$("img").draggable({ revert: 'invalid'});
$("img").addClass(classname,function(index,currentclass))
$("#itembox4").droppable()
$("#pricebox").droppable({ accept: '#price'});
$('#pricebox').droppable({ accept: '#price'});
$('#pricebox,#pricebox,#itembox4').bind('drop', function(ev,ui) {  itemInSpot(ui.draggable,this); });
 $('#itembox4 img').hide();

$('#clone_button').click(function() {
    $('#clone_wrapper div:#pricebox')
        .clone()
        .append('')
        .appendTo($('#clone_wrapper'));
})
});
$(function() {
$('#filter').change(function(){
    $('#itembox4 img').hide();
    $('.'+$(this).val()).show();});
});
```

I have added `$("img").addClass(classname,function(index,currentclass))` however once I move my image it loses its **id** and when i drag it back to its box it wont let me re drag it out.

**What am I trying to Achieve?**
Movable images that either don't lose their **id** or it automatically re adds once placed after being dragged and dropped.

http://jsfiddle.net/NHbpX/

*images are all dead but they all still work with jquery.*

**What I've tried**
Changing the items back to `class="price"` instead of `id="price"`

Comment: If you look at your JS Fiddle, you might notice lots of red in the HTML pane. This shows you've got problems with unclosed attributes. Incidentally, there are many image-placeholder sites on the internet (such as [lorem pixel](http://lorempixel.com/) and [(placekitten)](http://placekitten.com/), among others). Oh, and don't ask us to 'disregard the `--><--`,' if it's not meant to be there, don't put it there.

Comment: somehow I don't think this is causing my problems.

Comment: Possibly not, but it looks messy and makes it harder to help.

Comment: after further inspection it seems once its dragged it keeps its class however its `id="price"` is what seems to go missing.